# Using a cipherInputStream and FileInputStream together for unencrypted and encrypted access together

Tags: java

I have file which contains the beginning contains unencrypted header data and then the rest of the contains encrypted header data.
I want to be able to read the header data using a BufferedInputStream/ FileInputSteam.
Next I want to start reading the rest of the  encrypted data using CipherInputStream that uses the same BuffereredInputStream as input

Is this allowable??? Is it Ok to change the way you are using a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

The only tricky part depends on the structure of the header. If you have to read past the end of the header in order to determine where it ends, you'll need to be able to back up a bit in the stream so that the `CipherInputStream` can read all of the encrypted data. On the other hand, if your header has a fixed length, or it's length-encoded, or it has some sort of end marker, it should be quite simple:

```
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(...))) {
  Header header = Header.read(is);
  CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputstream(is, header.getCipherInstance());
  cis.read(...);
}
```